# sqlbulkcopy with notifyafter and transactions

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, sqlbulkcopy

I have the following code, which im trying to use to test out if its possible to have transactions and a notifyAfter property used to raise an event(i have already tried substituting the event for one i create/raise myself but it only gets raised after all the rows have been copied). The following link suggests that its not possible

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied.aspx)

Has anyone had any experience with this? Thanks

```
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                {
                        try
                        {
                            using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity |SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))

                            {
                                //Column mapping for the required columns.
                                for (int count = 0; count < numberOfColumns; count++)
                                {
                                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(count, count);
                                }

                                //SQLBulkCopy parameters.
                                copy.DestinationTableName = dataTableName;
                                copy.BatchSize = batchSize;

                                copy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
                                copy.NotifyAfter = 5;

                                copy.WriteToServer(fullDataTable);
                            }
                        }
                        //Error(s) occured while trying to commit the transaction.
                        catch (InvalidOperationException transactionEx)
                        {
                            //uploadTransaction.Rollback();
                            status = "The current transaction has been rolled back due to an error. \n\r" + transactionEx.Message;
                            MessageBox.Show(status, "Error Message:");
                            alreadyCaught = true;
                            throw;
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would presume because of the transaction, the processing only occurs after the transaction is committed hence you won't get the event raised until after that.

Comment: The above code does raise the event. If i set the batch sizing to 10 and the NotifyAfter property to 5, the event gets raised. First time = nothing in DB. 2nd = 10 rows and so on till all rows are added. So im assuming the transaction isnt working but im not sure how to test this. Thanks for your help.